# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable: Quadratic

Tags: python, error-handling, python-2.7, quadratic

(Finding the values of x in a quadratic equation w/o importing.) Whenever I run the program, Python stops at `discriminant = (b ** 2) - 4(a * c)` and shows TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. What's wrong?

```
#------SquareRootDefinition---------#
def Square_Root(n, x):
if n > 0:
    y = (x + n/x) / 2
    while x != y:
        x = y
        return Square_Root(n, x)
    else:
        if abs(10 ** -7) > abs(n - x ** 2):
            return y
elif n == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return str(int(-n)) + "i"

#----------Quadratic Equation--------------#

a = input("Enter coefficient a: ")
while a == 0:
    print "a must not be equal to 0."
    a = input("Enter coefficient a: ")
b = input("Enter coefficient b: ")
c = input("Enter coefficient c: ")

def Quadratic(a, b, c):
    discriminant = (b ** 2) - 4(a * c)
    if discriminant < 0:
        print "imaginary"
    elif discriminant >= 0:
        Sqrt_Disc = Square_Root(discriminant)
        First_Root = (-b + Sqrt_Disc) / (2 * a)
        Second_Root = (-b - Sqrt_Disc) / (2 * a)

  return First_Root, Second_Root

X_1, X_2 = Quadratic(a, b, c)
```

Comment: BTW, the code's not finished yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use `4` as a function:

```
discriminant = (b ** 2) - 4(a * c)
```

You missed `*`:

```
discriminant = (b ** 2) - 4 * (a * c)
```

Also, if your discriminant turns out to be lower than 0, you'll get an unbound local exception:

```
>>> X_1, X_2 = Quadratic(2, 1, 1)
imaginary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in Quadratic
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'First_Root' referenced before assignment
```

You'll need to add a `return` there, or better still, raise an exception:

```
def Quadratic(a, b, c):
    discriminant = (b ** 2) - 4(a * c)
    if discriminant < 0:
        raise ValueError("imaginary")
    elif discriminant >= 0:
        Sqrt_Disc = Square_Root(discriminant)
        First_Root = (-b + Sqrt_Disc) / (2 * a)
        Second_Root = (-b - Sqrt_Disc) / (2 * a)

    return First_Root, Second_Root
```

Your `Square_Root()` function is missing it's default value for `x`:

```
def Square_Root(n, x=1):
```

With those changes, your function actually works:

```
>>> Quadratic(1, 3, -4)
(1, -4)
```

Comment: Help: since the Square_Root function requires 2 parameters, what would I add inside `Sqrt_Disc = Square_Root(discriminant)` for Quadratic to work?

Comment: @user1947570: you mean you don't know how to use the recursive function `Square_Root()`? Tsk. tsk.

Answer (score 7):

`4(a * c)` is not valid Python.  You mean `4 * a * c`.  You can use juxtaposition and omit the multiplication symbol in mathematical notation, but not in Python (or most other programming languages).

Comment: Thank you @BrenBarn. You mean the only issue is the operation?

Comment: @user1947570: The only issue is the way you wrote the operation.  You have to actually write the multiplication symbol (`*`).

Comment: Imagine if you wrote `a (b * c)`. Is `a` a function? Or is `a` something you want to multiply? Because of this ambiguity, multiplication cannot be implicit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `4 * (a * c)` or just `4 * a * c` because python thinks you are trying to call a function `4`